# Codeigniter: Call to a member function view() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started a simple php project by using codeigniter framework and my steps are following.

1. Create a controller named `user.php`.
2. After that created a view `articles_list.php` inside the sub directory `public`.
3. After that loaded view in controller.

but getting fatal error call to a member function view() on null.
for this i am using 3.2.1 version of codeigniter framework.

I am beginner in this framework.Please tell me where I am wrong.

**user.php (Controller)**

```
<?php
class User extends MY_Controller{
public function __construct() {        
parent::__construct();
}
public function index(){
    echo "list articles";
    $this->load->view('public/articles_list');
}
}
?>
```

**articles_list.php (View)**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Article List</title>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/codeigniter/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
</head>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Error like this..

list articles
A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: User::$load

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 8

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\user.php
Line: 8
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once


Fatal error: Call to a member function view() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\user.php on line 8
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function view() on null

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 8

Backtrace:
```

Comment: Please check if the file is in your application/views/ directory ?

Comment: yes sure, this file path is application/view/public/articles_list.php

Comment: `class User extends CI_Controller` Try with this also remove visibility from function name

Comment: Please copy paste your entire error here.

Comment: @Punit Gajjar.. please see my edited post.

Comment: @user6891871 try `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');` in your autoload.php let me know if it helps

Comment: still it's showing error

Answer (score 3):

If you have use update Ci than try it :

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the name of that model into your config > autoload file.

Answer (score -1):

The controller

```
<?php
    class User extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()   {
          $this->load->database(); 
        }

        public function show($id) {
            $this->load->model('User_model');
            $list = $this->User_model->get_list($id);
            $data['detail'] = list;
            $this->load->view('list', $data);
        }
    }
?>
```

The Model

```
<?php
    class User_model extends CI_Model {
        public function __construct()   {
          $this->load->database(); 
        }

        public function get_list($id) {
           if($id != FALSE) {
               $query = $this->db->get_where('list', array('id' => $id));
               return $query->result();
           }
           else {
               return FALSE;
           }
        }
    }
?>
```

The View

```
<?php
    foreach($detail as $row){
        <?php print $row->field1; ?>
        <?php print $row->field2; ?>
    }
?>
```

For more information

[codeigniter views](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

[codeigniter models](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Answer (score -1):

Save your controller as User.php. Note that **U** is capitalized. In codeigniter versions 3.1.0 and above versions, file names of controllers and models needed to be saved like **U**ser.php.
Also change **MY_Controller** to **CI_Controller**

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

**actually, MY_Controller code should look like:-**

```
<?php 

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // echo "Testing";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

**actually MY_Controller code should looks like :-**

Comment: I believe you haven't completed your post. Use the "edit" link to edit the post so you can receive better help.